# Having Trouble Removing Item From Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, state

Upon loading the page, data is retrieved from my API and stored in an array. It then displays a button for each object in the array and titles is appropriately.

What needs to happen next is when I click a button, that button disappears, and the associated item removed from the array. That part is not working.  The button is registering the click, and the function is running.  However the button does not disappear, and when I log the array again, the array appears to be unchanged. I cannot figure out why. Can anyone help me spot the issue?

Here is my code, the part in question is the "handleAddPolicy" function:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import PolicyButton from './PolicyButton/PolicyButton';

class Handbook extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            clients: [],
            policies: [],
            client: 'Choose Client',
            logo: '',
            color1: '#000',
            color2: '#fff'
        };
        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/themes/all')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                this.setState({ clients: result });
                console.log(result);
            })
            .then(
                fetch(`/api/policy/all`)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then((result) => {
                        this.setState({ policies: result });
                        console.log(result);
                    })
            );
    }

    handleAddPolicy = policyId => {
        console.log(`button clicked`);
        const policies = this.state.policies.filter(policy => policy.id !== policyId);
        this.setState({ policies: policies});
        console.log(this.state.policies);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Fragment>
                {/* <ClientPicker /> */}
                <div className='buttons'>
                    {this.state.policies.map(policy => (
                        <PolicyButton key={policy.id} policy={policy.policy} onAddPolicy={this.handleAddPolicy} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Handbook;
```

And here is code for my button that should disappear after being clicked if it helps:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class PolicyButton extends Component {
    
    state = {
        id: this.props.id, 
        policy: this.props.policy
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <button onClick={() => this.props.onAddPolicy(this.props.id)}>{this.props.policy}</button>
        )
    }
}

export default PolicyButton;
```

Comment: setState is async so it will only change the state after your fn stack is cleared (and many more things)

Comment: You've not passed id as prop

Comment: Ah, ok, that has fixed part of the issue now. The buttons are disappearing, and items are being removed from the array. But it's not the correct items. They do not seem to be based on the actual item id numbers in my array. I can't actually tell how it's determining which one be removed.  It is logging the correct id for the button clicked.  But what is being removed from the array almost seems random, and there's one left over in the array after all the buttons are gone.

Comment: Also, console logging state immediately after `setState` call will only log current state, not the next state queued up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `id` prop when rendering `PolicyButton`

```
            <Fragment>
                {/* <ClientPicker /> */}
                <div className='buttons'>
                    {this.state.policies.map(policy => (
                        <PolicyButton
                          key={policy.id}
                          /* This is what you missed */
                          id={policy.id}
                          policy={policy.policy}
                          onAddPolicy={this.handleAddPolicy}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </Fragment>
```

Comment: Ah, ok, that has fixed part of the issue now.  The buttons are disappearing, and items are being removed from the array.  But it's not the correct items.  They do not seem to be based on the actual item id numbers in my array.  I can't actually tell how it's determining which one be removed.